# How to add QT application icon which can be shown on ubuntu desktop(gnome) and Activities

Tags: qt, icons, qt5, gnome

I'm writing a program with qt5 and I want create application icon which can be displayed on desktop(gnome), also within Activities(on top left of desktop) of Ubuntu when I type my application name to search for it. I'm using cmake to build my application with QtCreator

My environment:

```sh
Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS 64bits
QT 5.15.0
CMake 3.10.0
g++ 7.5.0
```

My method is create a `MyApplication.desktop` file within ~/.local/share/applications.

**My first try**

The icon diplayed is default icon(two gears with purple background) when search `MyApplication` within Activities.

`MyApplication.desktop`

```sh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/someuser/Documents/MyApplication/release/MyApplication
Path=/home/someuser/Documents/MyApplication/release
Name=MyApplication
GenericName=Start up MyApplication
Icon=MyApplicationIcon
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;MyApplication;
```

Here is my tree of application directory

```sh
~/Documents/MyApplication/release$ tree
.
├── libraries
├── MyApplication
└── MyApplicationIcon.png
```

So I think if the icon file cannot be found due to the relative path? So I changed my `MyApplication.desktop`, and

**My second try** make no changes of  the tree and files of application root.

This time, icon is blank or transparent or something else? Anyway, there is only a blank square with `MyApplication` name in bottom of that square after I typed `MyApplication` within Activities

Modified `MyApplication.desktop`

```sh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/someuser/Documents/MyApplication/release/MyApplication
Path=/home/someuser/Documents/MyApplication/release
Name=MyApplication
GenericName=Start up MyApplication
Icon=/home/isee/Documents/VisTrack/release/MyApplicationIcon
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;MyApplication;
```

Comment: @PabloRecalde I'm sorry, but I still cannot get thing working after reading that guide.